# Can a 'bug bomb' (pesticide fogger) kill a wasp nest in my attic?

Tags: pest-control

I have a wasp nest in the very peak of my roof inside my attic. The location and building design means I cannot get close enough to use either powder or foam spray products which I have done in the past. I can't really even get to the nest to see how big it is, I can just see them streaming between by roof tiles in a spot I cannot get to. I have work on the house and the nest needs to go.

I have used "smoke bombs" before where you light a wick and they disperse pesticide to fill an enclosed space for instance if you have a loft with a lot of flies. However I am not sure if it would be effective against a wasp nest which is quite enclosed, especially since the main nest entrance appears to be through a gap in my roof tiles. Is this likely to be an effective treatment or will the nest protect the insects?

Comment: And yes, I know calling a professional is another option. I'm not going to go close to the nest or take risks.

Comment: Also, provide a picture of the nest itself if possible.

Comment: Usually most wasps are of the type of you don't bother them, they don't bother you.  If not getting into the living space and you don't use the attic, might be better to leave them alone.  Pesticides do tend to get into living space and while killing the wasps might go where you don't want.

Comment: I can't safely get access to the nest from inside. If I could, I would just just use one of those long-distance spray-foam cans. So either I fog the whole space or I get a pro in. I suppose I can try a fogger and see.

Answer (score 2):

How about putting a DIY wasp trap in your attic or around your house?

Once enough of them die then the nest will die.

[image]

---

**Anecdote**

I had a bee nest forming inside the wall behind my cedar siding because of a deteriorating shingle on the lower course.

The nest grew for about 3 years as I hoped the winter cold would kill them but it didn't and eventually we couldn't really use that side of the house.

I could see one specific area of the deteriorated shingle which the bees were using it as the entrance/exit.

One day I decided to get my shop vac, attach as many extensions as I had, about 15 feet worth, and plant the nozzle at their entrance.

For about 2 hours I was turning on and off my vacuum while watching the bees enter and exit. I must have sucked up well over 100-200 bees. After a few weeks there was absolutely no activity at the entrance.

To note, I did call a few bee removal services and they were simply not interested due to the inaccessible location of the hive and the small number of bees that I reported. They're interested in easily accessible swarms.

Comment: can you really collapse a nest that way reliably? In some countries you can buy slow-acting poison bait that the wasps take back to the nest which would be ideal but I believe it's not allowed here.

Comment: @Mr.Boy Absolutely, see my update.

Comment: Bees produce honey.  Honey good.  Next time, quite a few bee keepers will collect the bees and nest if possible.

Comment: @crip659 I called around. Due to the inaccessible conditions and relatively small number, they were simply not interested. I was also not particularly interested in tearing up my house either. Bee keepers are interested in easily accessible swarms; aka thousands of bees. If I had a swarm then my vacuuming efforts would have been futile. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I had a hornets nest (nasty!) about 3m away from the bedroom window, I used a 3m piece of 1" overflow pipe, and blew a special chemical into it, using a footpump (not my mouth). That kept me away from the critturs, while covering all and returning insects so they all died off soon. Overflow pipe will stay sort of rigid to maybe 4-5m.

It's best done when it's night-time, when most if not all have returned to the nest. The problem with that is it's dark in your loft, and as soon as you shine a light to see what's happening, they'll all be up in arms.

I now keep a complete beekeepers outfit in case of return. Not too expensive, and in your predicament, would be wearing it as I went into the loft. Sorry, can't find the name of the chemical, or even if it's available in your part of the world, or even to the public any more. After all, health and safety, it's lethal - at least to wasps and hornets. Are you certain they're wasps and not bees? Bees are pretty harmless, and beneficial. Haven't yet found a use for wasps and hornets though...

If all else fails, surely pest control will come out, charge you lots, and solve the problem.

Comment: wasps actually have a lot of uses - they are 'garbage collectors' and eat many common pests. You just don't want their nest anywhere you might stumble upon!